# C++ - Calculating final values of x and y with a specific function

Tags: c++, function

I really do not have any clue about how to solve this task, can someone please help?

Consider the following function definition:

```cpp
void f(int i, int &j) {
    j = i+1;
    i = j*2;
    j += i; 
}
```

In the following code:

```
int x = 4, y = 7;
f(x, y);
```

What are the final values of `x` and `y`?

Comment: What is stopping you from simply running the code for yourself and outputting the final values to see what they actually are? For example, [see this demo](https://ideone.com/8F8Ew9);

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? What `int &j` means? What function is? How to multiply two numbers?

Comment: @Nana, [take a look](https://ideone.com/wQcgBD)

Comment: To answer this question You need to know: 1} what is a function, and how does it work 2) diffrent ways of passing parameters : by refrence and by value.

Comment: Note: Run it and see can be a bit risky. It sucks when inexperience leads you into trusting undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you could just run the code... but otherwise we can try and predict the output.

For starters the function f has two parameters, i and j. The & Infront of the j means that the value of the function input is passed by reference (the value of the variable will be edited).

So now let's evaluate the function with inputs 4, 7. We get:

```
j = 4+1 = 5
i = 10
j += i, j = 15
```

Because the variable y was passed by reference, its value will become 15. The variable x was passed by value, so it doesn't get affected and thus stays as 4.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just run the code.Anyway the output will be

x=4(because it is passed as pass by value ->any change will not affect the outside the function f)
y=15(because it is passed as pass by reference->any change will affect the outside the function f)